# Android Development play multiple sound files on button click

Tags: android, audio, button, onclick

I am using the following to play a sound on a button click:

```
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(menu.this, R.raw.button_sound);  
info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonSound.start();
```

Is it possible to add code that allows the button to play a sound, then wait for a second, and then play another sound file? What I am really asking is how I can play multiple CONSECUTIVE sound files! I need them to be played one at a time with a pause! I am working on a personal reading app for my son and would be so grateful for advice/help.

Comment: can you find anything that will be called after a sound file finishes playing? something like onSoundCompleted etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buttonSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // play another sound here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a SoundPool, preload the sounds, and use Handler.postDelayed to play the different sounds on a delay in response to the button clicks.